# Как обрезать изображение в виде "Треугольника"?

Tags: изображения, gd, php

Приветствую. 
Что имеем: есть страница, на ней расположен коллаж изображений в виде треугольников (один к другому, расстояние ~1px). Пользователь загружает изображение на сервер (только png с прозрачностью) и на "выходе" видит это изображение в виде треугольной картинки. Интерфейс для правильного позиционирования угла пока что не рассматриваем.

Задача: "выделить" изображение по треугольной области, а якобы пустоту от треугольника сделать прозрачной, чтобы потом сложить все изображения на странице.

Мысли: мы имеем на выходе изображение определенного размера. Думаю, что нужно инверсировать область треугольника, залить определенным цветом, заменить цвет на прозрачность. Но возможно ли так? В этой области не силен.

Буду рад увидеть ссылки на какие либо обвертки, советы и возможные "не совсем, но почти" решения задачи.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хм... А в справку GD сложно залезть?

[imagefilledpolygon()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagefilledpolygon.php)

**Обновление**

http://php.su/functions/?ImageColorTransparent

А если честно, не понимаю, зачем так извращаться. Я тоже как-то решил вырезать круглое превью для какого-то сайта. В итоге посмотрели на качество обрезания и количество потребляемых ресурсов, и решили вопрос средствами верстки дополнительным слоем поверх квадратного изображения. Так что просто рекомендую пересмотреть верстку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нет, не сложно. Как нарисовать фигуру на определенное количество полигонов и залить ее я знаю. Как из этого получить инверсированное изображение тоже знаю. А как заменить инверсию на "прозрачность"?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Конечно же легче было бы сделать это с помощью верстки. Но суть в том, что на странице "треугольники" будут отображатся в несколько клолнок, прижатые к друг другу. Задача на стадии "продумывания", скорее всего этот момент будет обработан в связке php+flash, так как есть множество нюансов, которые не реализуются одной версткой. А, например, с помощью javascript это будет ресурсо емко. 

Еще раз спасибо.